# Hardware acceleration without X

Tags: linux, opengl-es, embedded, arm, xorg

I was wondering if it would be possible to get graphical hardware acceleration without Xorg and its DDX driver, only with kernel module and the rest of userspace driver. I'm asking this because I'm starting to develop on an embedded platform (something like beagleboard or more roughly a Texas instruments ARM chip with integrated GPU), and I would get hardware acceleration without the overhead of a graphical server (that is not needed).

If yes, how? I was thinking about OpenGL or OpengGLES implementations, or Qt embedded http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt-embeddedlinux-accel.html

And TI provides a large documentation, but still is not clear to me
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Sitara_Linux_Software_Developer%E2%80%99s_Guide

Thank you.

Comment: Ew. http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Support%2FGraphics

Comment: And if you look at the block diagram in the Qt link I provided, there is no need even of directfb

Comment: It is absolutely POSSIBLE. It's largely a question of "what do you actually want/need beyond the basic graphics functionality". And of course, it also becomes a question of availability of suitable software - e.g. if the driver is written to support X, then you may need to have at least rudimentary X support. It all depends on what drivers you have available. On mobile phones, it tends to be OpenGL, OpenVG and EGL that builds the graphics subsystem - this applies to iPhone, android and Symbian based phones of modern standing (e.g. Nokia N8 and co). I have a feeling Windows not on Windows.

Comment: I'd need only hardware accelerated 3D graphics (OpenGL or OpenGLES doesn't matter), no windowing system, no input handling etc. So if the hardware manufacturer provides EGL support (is it more often than Xorg one?) i can provide OpenGL a render context, is it correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *answer* will depend on your user application.  If everything is *bare metal* and your application team is writing everything, the [DirectFB API](http://directfb.org/docs/DirectFB_Reference_1_6/index.html) can be used as Fredrik suggest.  This might be especially interesting if you use the framebuffer version of GTK.

However, if you are using Qt, then this is not the best way forward.  Qt5.0 does away with QWS ([Qt embedded acceleration](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embeddedlinux-accel.html)).   Qt is migrating to *LightHouse*, now known as [**QPA**](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Platform-Abstraction).  If you write a *QPA* plug-in that uses your graphics acceleration by whatever kernel mechanism you expose, then you have  *accelerated* Qt graphics.   Also of interest might be the [Wayland architecture](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/architecture.html); there are **QPA** plug-ins for **Wayland**.  Support exists for **QPA** in Qt4.8+ and Qt5.0+.  [Skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) is also an interesting graphics API with support for an OpenGL backend; Skia is used by Android devices.

Getting graphics acceleration is easy.  Do you want compositing?  What is your memory foot print?  Who is your developer audience that will program to the *API*?  Do you need *object* functionality or just drawing primitives?  There is a big difference between *SKIA*, *PegUI*, *WindML* and full blown graphics frameworks (Gtk, Qt) with all the widget and dynamics effects that people expect today. Programming to the [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) API might seem fine at first glance, but if your application has any complexity you will need a richer graphics framework; Mostly re-iterating **Mats Petersson's** comment.

**Edit:** From the [Qt embedded acceleration](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embeddedlinux-accel.html) link,

1. CPU blitter - slowest
2. [Hardware blitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blitter) - Eg, directFB. Fast memory movement usually with bit ops as opposed to machine words, like DMA.
3. 2D vector - OpenVG, Stick figure drawing, with bit manipulation.
4. 3D drawing - OpenGL(ES) has polygon fills, etc.

This is the type of drawing you wish to perform.  A framework like *Qt* and *Gtk*, give an API to put a radio button, checkbox, editbox, etc on the screen.  It also has styling of the text and interaction with a keyboard, mouse and/or touch screen and other elements.  A *framework* uses the drawing engine to put the *objects* on the screen.

Graphics acceleration is just putting algorithms like a [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) in a separate CPU or dedicated hardware.  If the framework you chose doesn't support *3D* objects, the frameworks is unlikely to need OpenGL support and **may** not perform any better.

The final piece of the puzzle is a [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager).  Many embedded devices do not need this.  However, many handset are using *compositing* and *alpha* values to create transparent windows and allow multiple apps to be seen at the same time.  This may also influence your graphics API.

Additionally: [DRI without X](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DriWithoutX/) gives some compelling reasons why this might not be a good thing to do; for the case of a single user task, the **DRI** is not even needed.

The following is a diagram of a **Wayland** graphics stack a [blog on Wayland](http://ppaalanen.blogspot.ca/2012/03/what-does-egl-do-in-wayland-stack.html).

[image: Wayland diagram]

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting answer. I would know something more about the driver stack I need in the various situations. So, if I only need bare 3D graphics I use only the kernel module+OpenGL implementation (I guess). If I need, say, GTK, I use DirectFB, but in this case add the DirectFB driver to the stack. If I need a very rich GUI I use Qt, and I don't know what I must add to the stack.

Comment: My main concern are the DRIVERS. In the ARM-Linux world this is a delicate question (just see what Broadcom did with RaspberryPi). Sometimes you have the entire stack closed, sometimes the entire stack minus DDX, sometimes nothing.

Comment: Can you explain me, please?

Comment: Ok, I just read your edit. So what I actually need is fourth type of hardware acceleration, 3D drawing with OpenGL ES. With this I suppose i will able to write my own toolkit (buttons, checkboxes, font rendering etc.) and windowing system. I just want to squeeze the most from the GPU, then be free to do whatever I want with it.

Comment: [Free Open source graphic drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_graphics_device_driver) at Wikipedia has some relevant information to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is depend on soc gpu driver implement ,
On iMX6 ,you can use wayland composite on framebuffer 
I build a sample project as a reference

[Qt with wayland on imx6D/Q](https://github.com/liyaoshi/buildroot.git)

On omap3 there is a project

[omap3 sgx wayland](https://github.com/nemomobile/ti-omap3-sgx-wayland-wsegl)