# GUI Library for Microcontrollers on Linux platform

Tags: linux, user-interface, arm, microcontroller

I have been working with a lpc1788 (Cortex M3) evaluation board. For some application developement I used a GUI library/tool by Segger, called emWin. Though I have completed the applicatiopn developement on keil uVision 4, I am keen to whether the same can be done on a linux gnu-arm toolchain used along with a GUI library. As the name itself suggests, emWin is not meant for linux platform developement. And, its costly too not being an open source. Can anybody please inform me if there are any options available?

Comment: [Hardware acceleration without X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615342/hardware-acceleration-without-x) maybe of some help.  Even if your chip doesn't have graphics acceleration most of the tool kits mentioned support both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QT](http://qt-project.org/) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) both have ports for embedded systems, especially those that are capable of running a decent linux distro such as your arm board.

1. QT Embeded packs it's own window manager.. and doesn't seem to need X11. [link to Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Support_for_Embedded_Linux)
2. wxWidgets usually wraps around other GUI libs. [Link to Articles](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/embedded.htm)
   There's :-

   - wxGTK for GTK+ if you squeeze GTK into your device.
   - wxX11 if you can get an X Window system to run on your device.
   - wxDFB for "resource free" devices that use [DirectFB](http://directfb.org)
   - wxNano-X for [Nano-X](http://www.microwindows.org/)

There should be other options out there, but you may the above because:-

- They have excellent community support.
- Both libraries are Free and Open Source.
- They have very nice development tools...IDEs and RAD tools that are Free & Open Source.
- Ease of development of your GUIs on desktop.
- Portability of your app to other platforms ( Android, win32/64, OSX ..etc ).
- .....The list goes on and on.

Comment: *Qt* is considered quite **heavy** by some people.  It is a minimum of about 5MB and will probably be closer to 10MB unless you remove many features.  *Qt* is used by the *BlackBerry Playbook* and newer *Q10/Z10* cell-phones.  It is also the frame-work used by older Nokia cell-phones.  If the memory requirements don't scare you, then it is a good choice; it provides the base for [*KDE*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE), but can be configured to use a Linux *frame buffer* directly.

Comment: Qt is dual licensed. If you're developing a commercial product, you'll possibly not want to be using LGPL libraries on your product.  The commercial option is not prohibitive and will certainly compare very favourably the the cost of your time using a poorly documented and unsupported alternative.

Comment: @Marko LGPL is permissive enough to allow commercial use. The only catch is that if he modifies the LGPL'd QT libs, he has to share the changes to the QT Libs but not his code.

Comment: @Moje He'd also need to release binaries of his parts of the system to satisfy the license.  Even this is enough to give big corporate the heebeegeebees. 
However, the other point here is that with the commercial license comes support.  You wouldn't need a developer to get stuck for very long to more than cover the cost of it.

Comment: @Marko The commercial licence costs may be unrealistic depending on his business model. He may also have to pass those costs over to his customers, giving the competition potential cost advantage. Support is hardly a big deal...QT is open and has a very shallow learning curve. It hardly ever misbehaves but when it does, there is a large community of QT developers eager to torpedo those problems for free :)...and besides that, there's STACKOVERFLOW!