# graphics engine for embedded systems

Tags: graphics, embedded

i am a newbie at graphics for embedded system. i have worked with OpenGl, Unity, WPF etc for graphics but as a hobby project i wanted to run games on embedded platforms like [arduino and Raspberry(without Raspian)].

Can someone please refer some guide or road map for me in this regard. For performance issue i want to target only 2D but good proper games and the system should work like a gaming console. [off course the game controllers are least of my worries since i am an electrical engineer :D ].

Please don't close this question without answer. i know there are a lot others but i wanted answer to my problem for 2D games ...

P.S. i would really appreciate solutions that are widely accepted,

Comment: Arduino are chalk and cheese - so that is probably two separate questions.  The biggest problem with using RPi without one of the supported Linux or RiscOS based OSes is the closed GPU - although Broadcom are I think opening that up a bit recently, and Arduino does not have a single defined graphics interface.

Comment: See: [Hardware acceleration without X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615342/hardware-acceleration-without-x); the possibilities are even larger when not tied to an OS.  There are many different parts to a *graphics engine*; Google [graphics pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline).

Comment: thanks for the replies, so you guys think the [heavy] proper way would be the only way???i have worked with text graphics drivers where i did not have any GPU at all and  used GPIOs with a bit of hacks {but those were hardwired into FPGA},,, ok if i go for Qt would that still be impossible on arduino? remember i target only 2d at the moment, which is not much friends with most GPUs.

Comment: @RisaldarGreenWitch You can integrate Qt with Yocto (set of tools that enables you to create your own custom Linux) rather well including rendering without X and even having stuff like touch support. Hardware (GPU-based) acceleration is also available. However 1)Qt is not an engine and 2)if space is of the essence you will have to go with static linking which immediately changes the licensing and price model of Qt to commercial, which is rather expensive. Running Qt on Arduino is as far as I know not possible due to the limited resources Arduino has available.