# Embedded Linux with Standalone application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I want to make Linux Os which run only one application as a full screen without showing any Login window at start up or title-bar and minimize/maximize/close button.

Is there any way to do this? It's Embedded platform and I already build Linux os for it and I also have application.

Comment: What is your application? The question is extremely broad, but.. there is something like Qt/Embedded. You can start X manually, and point DISPLAY=:0 whateverXapp with the right parameters to make it fullscreen... you can use minimalistic window manager (I love ratpoison for these tasks).

Comment: My application is based on home automation and written in .net

Comment: I presume you've built it on Linux with Mono and it runs well?

Comment: Yes. all is runs well.

Comment: Please include this additional information in the comments in your post (I think you can edit it), and I'll answer your question :)

Comment: Also add some information on the Linux OS you've built. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The system is based on Linux os and I have build mono-runtime and Application is works well. It's controll Electronic device like Lamp, AC etc. remotely and it uses z-wave device. Now I want to make linux distro to run only this application and not showing any other thing.It's like homegenie, An opensource project.

Comment: See: [Hardware acceleration without X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615342/hardware-acceleration-without-x/).  At the most basic level, a memory mapped frame buffer allows you to draw on a screen.  I don't know why you would want to use 'X'.

Comment: Usually *"standalone program"* means a program that does not require an OS and runtime libraries.  So your title of "Linux with standalone program" makes no sense (to me).  Seems like you really mean a "single" or "solitary" app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the nutshell - X System is extremely flexible.

When you system starts up, it does the following steps:

1. Loads and runs the Kernel (and related initrd, if any, but it's irrelevant)
2. Starts init (process 1)
3. Starts system services, networking, etc.
4. Starts X server
5. Starts Window Manager (the application responsible for resizing windows etc)
6. Starts your application.

What you need to do, is to first disable GUI login and session (easiest to disable X) - you'll be able to log in through the console terminal (You can always access it with Ctrl-Alt-F1)

Then, launch something along the lines of

```
X &
DISPLAY=:0 ./yourapp.exe
```

If your app can handle making itself fullscreen, that would be it. 
Add this to your startup scripts and you're there.

---

**More explanation**

The purpose of the Window Manager.. is to manage windows. It's that simple :)

Basically, there are 3 components of your typical X session.

- X Server - the piece of software that provides an abstraction layer around the hardware (GPU drivers, Keyboard, Mouse, Touchscreen, etc). It has a concept of windows - areas where X Clients can draw into.
- X Clients - Everything else. Your software, if it draws something, is likely one. So is the web browser, etc. The connect to the X Server, and draw.
- Window Manager - A special type of an X Client, this piece of software provides the ability to control the windows on your screen. It often draws window decorations (minimize, maximize buttons), sometimes draws a taskbar, etc.

You are free to mix and match them entirely as you please. Simpler, minimalisting window managers, such as my `ratpoison` which I prefer for many prototype embedded systems only have the notion of fullscreen windows, and can switch between fullscreen apps (think Windows 8 Metro). Others draw window decorations, and allow overlapping and cascading windows.

Since developing a Window Manager is a simple and modular task, there are literally hundreds to chose from. You also can choose not to use one at all, at which point your windows have to self-manage (you'll not be able to move them around by default). Many applications respect the `-geometry 1920x1080+0+0` parameter, telling them to open a window in 1920x1080 resolution at the 0,0 corner - effectively fullscreen.

Comment: And one more thing. this also opens web-browser for interface. so, is it still working ?

Comment: You might want to start a minimalistic window manager if you want the windows to be managed in any way (foreground/background, maximized).. Or you can make your browser do that.

Comment: I can't understand. please elaborate it.

Comment: So **ratpoison** , according to you is best-one. right? and is it capable of handling High end graphics [My embedded hardware have support for high end graphics.].

Comment: It doesn't need to support any graphics. It's doing window *management*, and very rudimentary at that. The graphics part is between the client (your app, or the browser) and the X Server. All components are independent.

Comment: What if you just want a single window to take control of the screen, with no separate windows allowed or managed?